# Can we open Sliding drawer from somewhere middle on the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I want sliding drawer to open from middle of the screen, not from the left, right, top or bottom of the screen as it does normally .

Is it possible?
How can I do it ?

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have solved my problem. Solution is- take parent layout Relative Layout . In Sliding Drawer put

```
 android:layout_above="@+id/your_below_layout .
```

My problem was, i was using Linear Layout.
 Thanks